# C# .NET Why Stream.Seek is required when unzipping stream

Tags: c#, .net, zip, unzip, dotnetzip

I'm working on a project where I need the ability to unzip streams and byte arrays as well as zip them. I was running some unit tests that create the Zip from a stream and then unzip them and when I unzip them, the only way that DonNetZip sees them as a zip is if I run `streamToZip.Seek(o,SeekOrigin.Begin)` and `streamToZip.Flush()`. If I don't do this, I get the error "*Cannot read Block, No data*" on the `ZipFile.Read(stream)`.

I was wondering if anyone could explain why that is. I've seen a few articles on using it to actually set the relative read position, but none that really explain why in this situation it is required.

Here is my Code:

Zipping the Object:

```
   public Stream ZipObject(Stream data)
    {
        var output = new MemoryStream();
        using (var zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            zip.AddEntry(Name, data);
            zip.Save(output);
            FlushStream(output);
            ZippedItem = output;
        }

        return output;
    }
```

Unzipping the Object:

```
 public List<Stream> UnZipObject(Stream data)
    {
        ***FlushStream(data); // This is what I had to add in to make it work***

        using (var zip = ZipFile.Read(data))
        {
            foreach (var item in zip)
            {
                var newStream = new MemoryStream();
                item.Extract(newStream);
                UnZippedItems.Add(newStream);
            }
        }
        return UnZippedItems;
    }
```

Flush method I had to add:

```
    private static void FlushStream(Stream stream)
    {
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        stream.Flush();
    }
```

Comment: Where and, with what `Stream`, do you call `UnZipObject`? And moreover, what did you do with that `Stream` **before** calling `UnZipObject`?

Comment: what does `ZippedItem = output;` do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you return `output` from `ZipObject`, that stream is at the *end* - you've just written the data. You need to "rewind" it so that the data can then be read. Imagine you had a video cassette, and had just recorded a program - you'd need to rewind it before you *watched* it, right? It's exactly the same here.

I would suggest doing this in `ZipObject` itself though - and I don't believe the `Flush` call is necessary. I'd personally use the `Position` property, too:

```
public Stream ZipObject(Stream data)
{
    var output = new MemoryStream();
    using (var zip = new ZipFile())
    {
        zip.AddEntry(Name, data);
        zip.Save(output);
    }
    output.Position = 0;
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the real world analogy... just what I needed!

Answer (score 4):

When you write to a stream, the position is changed. If you want to decompress it (the same stream object), you'll need to reset the position. Else you'll get a `EndOfStreamException` because the `ZipFile.Read` will start at the `stream.Position`.

So

```
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Or

```
stream.Position = 0;
```

would do the trick.

---

Offtopic but sure useful:

```
public IEnumerable<Stream> UnZipObject(Stream data)
{
    using (var zip = ZipFile.Read(data))
    {
        foreach (var item in zip)
        {
            var newStream = new MemoryStream();
            item.Extract(newStream);
            newStream.Position = 0;
            yield return newStream;
        }
    }
}
```

Won't unzip all items in memory (because of the `MemoryStream` used in the `UnZipObject()`, only when iterated. Thats because extracted items are yielded. (returning an `IEnumerable<Stream>`) More info on yield: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9k7k7cf0.aspx

Normally i wouldn't recomment returning data as stream, because the stream is something like an iterator (using the .Position as current position). This way it isn't by default threadsafe. I'd rather return these memory streams as `ToArray()`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I have heard that a few times that it is best to pass byte arrays as opposed to streams, but I'm not sure I understand in your answer why? Can I have an example of what you are proposing?

Comment: An array can be read by multiple threads concurrent, a stream cannot because multiple threads will _change_ the `Position` property. Also the byte array will be a 'copy' of the original stream.